# How to convert from PAnsichar to PWidechar?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, indy10

I am implementing Ping function using windows API in delphi-xe3 from here
(http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/l/aa081503a.htm).

I am having problem with the following function.It displays error incompatible type Pansichar and Pwidechar.I replaced Pchar with PAnsichar now it displays exception
'Error getting IP from HostName'.

I am testing it with localhost.

Please guide whats the proper conversion.

```
const ADP_IP = '127.0.0.1';

procedure TranslateStringToTInAddr(AIP: string; var AInAddr);
var
  phe: PHostEnt;
  pac: PChar;
  GInitData: TWSAData;
begin
  WSAStartup($101, GInitData);
  try
    phe := GetHostByName(PChar(AIP));
    if Assigned(phe) then
    begin
      pac := phe^.h_addr_list^;
      if Assigned(pac) then
      begin
        with TIPAddr(AInAddr).S_un_b do begin
          s_b1 := Byte(pac[0]);
          s_b2 := Byte(pac[1]);
          s_b3 := Byte(pac[2]);
          s_b4 := Byte(pac[3]);
        end;
      end
      else
      begin
        raise Exception.Create('Error getting IP from HostName');
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      raise Exception.Create('Error getting HostName');
    end;
  except
    FillChar(AInAddr, SizeOf(AInAddr), #0);
  end;
  WSACleanup;
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to convert from `PAnsiChar` to `PWideChar`. On your Unicode Delphi your `PChar` maps to `PWideChar`. But `gethostbyname` receives `PAnsiChar`. You need to convert from Unicode to ANSI.

Code it like this:

```
phe := gethostbyname(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(AIP)));
```

In other words, convert your string to `AnsiString`, and then cast as `PAnsiChar`. Personally I'd declare the `AIP` parameter to be `AnsiString`.

```
procedure TranslateStringToTInAddr(const AIP: AnsiString; var AInAddr);
```

And then write the call to `gethostbyname` like so:

```
phe := gethostbyname(PAnsiChar(AIP));
```

That untyped `var` parameter looks dubious to me. I see no compelling reason for its use. What's wrong with declaring it to be of type `TIPAddr`? Your `FillChar` is somewhat dubious. How can you use `SizeOf` on an untyped parameter?

Comment: thanks @David , i did it ur way .now it didnt displayed any error but no message is either shown .i just took the code from the site and tried to compile it ,i m not much familiar with windows api's. so i dont know why its better to use var AIPaddr or something else.

Comment: Your code doesn't display messages. Anyway, my answer tells you what was wrong with your call to `gethostbyname`. The code in my answer does that correctly. Please don't expect me to debug the rest of your program. I answered the question that you asked. That's how SO works.

Comment: No i meant i implemented the whole code given in the link i pasted and it dispalys message.http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/l/aa081503a.htm  .Thanks a lot for your help, yes it did removed the error.

Comment: @XenonXe: by _message_ I understand your saying that not exceptions are being raised, so what you are saying is that the `gethostbyname()` function worked properly. However, I agree with @David that the `var` parameter should be typed as `TIpAddr`, since your code depends on that to work. The `FillChar` in the last exception block is misterious to me. Could you explain it?

Comment: @AlexSC The code was copied verbatim from the linked article which looks dubious to me. Your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: No i cant explain it coz its not my code. i need a ping function and tried this windows function. i m myself trying to understand the code. i need a little guidance here.should i implement it myself or use windows api?

Comment: I think i should post a new question for this guidance .Thanks a lot all .